# Measuring the time between keydown and keyup events

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to capture the timing in millisecond between the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, the elapsed time between those two events for each typed character, I used `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` since I need to acquire a high-resolution time stamps, as shown in the coding below, and I wonder if this is the correct equation to get the time in millisecond:

`int timeStampInMiliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(elapsedTicks * 1000000 / Stopwatch.Frequency);` for getting the time in millisecond.

Since the timing results does not show any consistency and could reach up to 5 seconds between those two events, which is not realistic!!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    long timeStamp;
    long initialTimeStamp;


    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
         // Uses the second Core or Processor for the Test
        // Prevents "Normal" processes from interrupting Threads
        // Prevents "Normal" Threads  
        initialize();

    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        //
    }

    public void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        initialTimeStamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    }

    public void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timeStamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        long elapsedTicks = timeStamp  -initialTimeStamp;

        int timeStampInMiliseconds = Convert.ToInt32(elapsedTicks * 1000000 / Stopwatch.Frequency);
    }
}
```

Really appreciating your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that pressing two keys at the same time, or using a modifier key will break this. for instance, press-hold Control, and then press another key and then release control..

Comment: In addition to caesay's comment - debugging makes results even more interesting as you get events with potentially huge delay if you stepping through the code.

Comment: @  caesay @Alexei Levenkov: Thank you for your answers, can you suggest a solution to the error. thanks

Comment: @Zaid it is hard to see what exactly you trying to do from your sample and  what measurement actually fails. Current code should measure interval between 2 nearest down/up pairs, but not necessary for the same key as far as I understand. Finding out and updating post with case when you get "5 seconds between ...events" may someone to provide an answer. (You may also consider asking separate question like "why when {exact condition you've discovered} down/up events are spaced 5 seconds".)

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this is to use the `StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` property.

In the `textBox1_KeyDown` event handler, simply restart the stop watch like this:

```
stopWatch.Restart();
```

And in the `textBox1_KeyUp` event handler, read the `ElapsedMilliseconds` property like this:

```
long timeStampInMiliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

You also need to make the `stopWatch` an instance variable like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    long timeStamp;
    long initialTimeStamp;
    Stopwatch stopWatch;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        ....

    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but the times were not consistant and and didn't capture all the timings for some reason. any suggestion please.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario that failed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `Stopwatch`. It is much easier to get a timestamp using:

```
long t = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Try this:

```
public void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    initialTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
}

public void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    timeStamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    long elapsedTicks = timeStamp - initialTimeStamp;

    long timeStampInNanoseconds = elapsedTicks * 100;
}
```

I did it in Nanoseconds for more accuracy, but you can convert to Milliseconds if you like:

```
long timeStampInMiliseconds = elapsedTicks / 10000;
```